# How bypass integrity error during OTA install of an IPA file?

Tags: ios, ota, integrity, over-the-air

I am currently working on a project allowing me to upload IPA (iOS) files to s3 bucket in order to install them on my iPhone using Over The Air (OTA).

The index.html file include the following link:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&;url=https://s3-eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/ipapk-ipa/plist.xml" class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Install</a>
```

And here the plist.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://s3-eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/ipapk-ipa/DVIA.ipa</string>
                </dict>

                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://s3-eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/ipapk-ipa/DVIA.ipa.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.highaltitudehacks.DVIAswiftv2</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>DVIA-v2</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When I click on the install button, the application starts to install but interrupt with "**This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified**"

Have you any idea?
PS : I have the same kind of error using tool such as https://www.diawi.com/

Comment: What type of build is it?  Enterprise? Ad-hoc?

Comment: Sounds like code signing. Also, jailbreaking. Any chance you could provide an example of an app that works?

Comment: I also have this problem.. this is an internal use app we use at our organization.. we used our active Apple Developer Enterprise Program to build it. We tried following this instructions for distribution: https://www.goodbarber.com/blog/how-to-distribute-ios-app-out-of-the-store-with-ios-enterprise-program-a871/  But users get "This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified""